# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$

Tags: calculus

> $$\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)~=~?$$

I keep on getting $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ as an answer: Please check my work.

[image]

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals). Also, for technical reasons, it is discouraged to use titles consisting only of $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you expand FOIL, you turned $\cos2x\cos2x$ into $\cos4x$.

Comment: while at it also explain why choose that identity rather than $\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x = \sin x \cos x$ to start

Comment: Because I am just starting out and want to know the tools I know. Nonetheless. I can use this identity but my foiling is flawed? I thought you werent able to multiply angles?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.  FOIL gives you $-\cos2x\cos2x$ as the L term.  That equals $-\frac12(1+\cos4x)$, not $\cos4x$

Comment: Okay I skipped a step. I shoud have left it as $ cos^2(2x)$ then utilied the half angle formula?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Comment: Michael - why is the angle 4x?

Comment: Because you double the angle.  If $y=2x$, then you have $\cos^2(y)=\frac12(1+\cos2y)=\frac12(1+\cos4x)$